# NO error display but cant slideUp();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this slide up and slide down. I can slide down the child on click but cant slide up when click again.

JavaScript

```
jQuery("#all li").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent  = jQuery(this);
    var father  = parent.data("clicked", true);
    var child   = parent.find("ul");
    var x       = child.on(":visible");
    if (parent.is(":visible")) {
        child.slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        child.slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul id="all">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, based on your posted script and markup, that the `parent` is always visible. This means the if statement has essentially no effect. Altering it to check if the `child` is visible may help:

```
$('#all li').on('click', function() {
    var parent = $(this);
  var child = parent.find('ul');

   if(child.is(':visible')){
   $(child).slideUp('fast');
   } else {
   $(child).slideDown('fast');
   }

});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5g84krhg/)**

Comment: i get it so ill change the parent in to child thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected result, use slideToggle()

JS:

```
jQuery("#all li").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parent = jQuery(this);

  var father = parent.data("clicked", true);
  var child = parent.find("ul");
  var x = child.on("visible");
  if (parent.is("visible")) {
    child.slideDown("fast");
  } else {
    child.slideToggle("fast");
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jAkjBd